# How do I extract first n elements from a document in a collection in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a MongoDB collection that has,

```
 { "_id" : ObjectId("5d6f69c1dc0f33f6740e46f8"), "A" : "1R", "B" : 0.67, "C" : 0.65, "D" : 0.6, "E" : 0.64}
 { "_id" : ObjectId("5d6f69c1dc0f33f6740e46f9"), "A" : "4G", "C" : 0.6, "V" : 0.5, "R" : 0, "O" : 11.0,"I" : 14}
 { "_id" : ObjectId("5d6f69c1dc0f33f6740e4610"), "A" : "3H", "W" : 0.4, "J" : 0.12, "H" : 2.0}
```

I want to extract the first two documents with first 3 elements. I am able to fetch the first two records using Limit function but the further extraction is where I am not able to proceed.

Expected Output:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d6f69c1dc0f33f6740e46f8"), "A" : "1R", "B" : 0.67, "C" : 0.65}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d6f69c1dc0f33f6740e46f9"), "A" : "4G", "C" : 0.6, "V" : 0.5}
```

How do I do this in mongoDB? Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

The following query can get us the expected output:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $limit:2
    },
    {
        $project:{
            "root":{
                $objectToArray:"$$ROOT"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            "root":{
                $slice:["$root",0,4]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            "root":{
                $arrayToObject:"$root"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot:{
            "newRoot":"$root"
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

**Data set:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d6f69c1dc0f33f6740e46f8"),
    "A" : "1R",
    "B" : 0.67,
    "C" : 0.65,
    "D" : 0.6,
    "E" : 0.64
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d6f69c1dc0f33f6740e46f9"),
    "A" : "4G",
    "C" : 0.6,
    "V" : 0.5,
    "R" : 0,
    "O" : 11,
    "I" : 14
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d6f69c1dc0f33f6740e4610"),
    "A" : "3H",
    "W" : 0.4,
    "J" : 0.12,
    "H" : 2
}
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d6f69c1dc0f33f6740e46f8"),
    "A" : "1R",
    "B" : 0.67,
    "C" : 0.65
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d6f69c1dc0f33f6740e46f9"),
    "A" : "4G",
    "C" : 0.6,
    "V" : 0.5
}
```

**Explanation:** We are converting the root documents to an array of key-value pairs, slicing the array to the required size, and then again converting the sliced array into the document.

*Note: I kept the slice size as 4 because objectId is also considered.*

Comment: This code works. I set the limit to 200 but it shows only 12.

Comment: Do you mean the initial limit or slice limit?